# Adding a constraint in UML class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I need to draw an UML class diagram which is made from the following statements.

*A house has an address and consists of several rooms. Each room has a size. It can either be a bedroom, a living room, or a kitchen. **A house consists of at least one of each kind of rooms.***

The last statement is a constraint, and I need to add it in my diagram.

[image: UML class diagram]

**UPD:** The whole task was the following.

*Draw a UML class diagram representing exactly the following scenario:
A family consists of an arbitrary number of children and one or two parents. Every
family member is a person with a name and an age. Children are able to play games and
parents can go to work and they can cook something in the kitchen. A family lives in a
house which has an address and which consists of several rooms. An arbitrary number
of families can live in a house. Each room has a size. It can either be a bedroom, a living
room, or a kitchen. A house consists of at least one of each kind of rooms. An arbitrary
number of persons sleeps in a bedroom.*

Comment: I think it is represented by a rhombus. I am not sure. For the keys it in bold and underlined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you wish to keep the Association between House and Room, you could create additional Associations to the individual room types, **sub-setting the Room end**.
[image: House and rooms subsetting associations]

The `{subsets Room}` means that these should be considered a part of the general `Room` association.

Comment: Does it make sense to have the types of rooms as subclasses rather than a "roomRole" association? I mean even the assignment says "A house consists of [...] kind of rooms". In real life you could swap living room/bedroom just by proclaiming so (and maybe moving some furniture).

Comment: I would omit the compositions from the specialized classes since they are inherited from `Room` anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I added an update with the whole task just in case. What do you think, am I allowed to omit the association between House and Room? And therefore draw only associations between House and all room types?

Comment: You still need a general association in order to add other types of rooms that have not been specified.

Comment: The specification says, that a room is either a bedroom, or a living room or a kitchen. In other words, there is no other type of room (by definition). In my opinion, the assocation between House and Room can be omitted.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl In that case Room should be made abstract, which would be a questionable decision. We all know that there are other room types beside the Kitchen, LivingRoom and BedRoom. But even then I would not opt to omit the general association. Surely there's merit in being able to get **all** rooms of the house at once without having to get them type by type.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, Yes, that's a good motivation for your solution, thanks. Leaving out the general association has two benefits, though: (1) Don't complicate the diagram because of uncertain future needs. Maybe the need to get all rooms at once will never occur and other types of room will never exist. (2) Most people are not familiar with the {subsets} notation. If your audience has limited knowledge of UML, it might cause misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

{subset} can be removed, because if one end of the association {redefine}, then the other must be a {subset}. End Association House (from Kitchen) {redefine} end of the Association House (from Room), because their names are the same.